# Angularjs Reference Error: service is not defined

Tags: angularjs, http, service, controller, q

I would like to inject my service file into my controller using AngularJS so I can make the $http calls, but when I do so, I receive an error that it isn't defined.

Here's my service call in a separate file that has been included into the index.html.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('App')
        .service('MemberService', ['$http', '$q',

function MemberService($http, $q) {

    var svc = this;
    svc.postMembers = _postMembers;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    _postMembers.$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/MemberSearch',
        data: data,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result)
    }, function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
    console.log("promise", deferred.promise);
}]);
})();
```

Now, here's the controller.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('App')   
    .controller('MemberController', MemberController);

MemberController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$q', 'MemberService', MemberService];

function MemberController($http, MemberService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.search = {}; //a blank object to contain form data
    vm.memberSearchForm = null; //reference to the actual form in html
    vm.memberResult = [];  //a blank object to handle returned data
    vm.memberSearch = _memberSearch;
    vm.showErrors = false;

    function _memberSearch() {

        vm.showErrors = true;            

        console.log("inside _memberSearch");

        var promisePost = MemberService.postMembers(vm.search)
        console.log("vm.search", vm.search);
    }

};
})();
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your injection is wrong in `MemberController`. Change into `MemberController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$q', 'MemberService']`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried that and it didn't recognize it. I still get an error that MemberService is undefined. Any other ideas?

Comment: There is a problem relating to your `_postMembers`. Change it like in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/agtxk1sy/) and it should work

Comment: @themyth92 Thanks for your help!  Yes, it was a subtle change, but it worked!